# How to save files in External Storage Public Directory DOCUMENTS on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, file, save, documents

i want to save a file on my Android 4.1.2 smartphone in the documents directory.

This code snippet:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"test.txt");
```

throws this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS
```

While this one is working:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"test.txt");
```

But i want to save my file in my documents directory, not in downloads. Ive read DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS is only available in Android 4.4 and higher. But there is also a documents direcotry on my smartphone. So, is there no solution to save it in documents?

Thx for answers

Pebbles

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are not able to access `DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` becuase it is not there in Android 4.1.2. Which means, though there is a Documents directory in your external storage, it is not pointed to by `DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` (since it is non-existent). To solve this, you have to create the directory if it is not present and get the path to that folder manually.

```
File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
boolean isPresent = true;
if (!docsFolder.exists()) {
    isPresent = docsFolder.mkdir();
}
if (isPresent) {
    File file = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(),"test.txt"); 
} else {
    // Failure
}
```

Comment: DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS does not exist on my Android 6 (ASUS Nexus 7) and can not be created via mkdir() even with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the manifest

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives a File back. I guess you need to add getAbsolutePath() to get a String. Concatenating "/Documents" should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

The folder is present in older Versions (from Api 1) of Android but the field DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS is available first in Version 4.4 (Api 19 - Kitkat).

Solution for me was to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents"` instead DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS for older Android Versions.